Chromebook LDE with Eclipse GUI flickering
ChromeOS Version 123.0.6312.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) with Linux Developer Environment enabled and Eclipse IDE installed (2024-03). When I run the application, parts of the Eclipse active window flicker depending on where the mouse pointer is located. I've seen posts going back a few years on this issue, but nothing recently, and no solutions.
Does anyone know the cause, and what is the status or resolution of this issue?
https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/270579135?hl=en

Does export GDK_BACKEND=x11; and/or export WEBKIT_DISABLE_DMABUF_RENDERER=1; before starting Eclipse from the command line help?

@howlger thanks for the suggestion. What worked was running sommelier for the Wayland compositor. I posted the solution as an answer.

SOLVED Eclipse runs without fonts flickering using the following command line args penguin:~$ sommelier -X --scale=1.0 eclipse/jee-2024-03/eclipse/eclipse from https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/wiki/howto/install-eclipse/
